# how to attach the pdf file that is present in program file throught mail

Tags: c#

am generating a pdf file in my c# code... i want to attach that pdf file and same to my mail id using attachment... can anyone help me in sending pdf through attachment internally using c# code

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can attach your pdf file as :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To = "mailgoesto@domain.com";
message.From = "mailcomesfrom@domain.com";
message.Subject = "mail with pdf";
message.Body = "your pdf attached";
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\pdftoattach.pdf"));

SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.domain.com";
SmtpMail.Send(message);
```